# Getting different JSON response in browser and Xcode console

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm using this [API](https://streamable.com/documentation) to parse a video link and get a direct link to that video. When I do the request in the browser here is what I get

[image: Reply in the browser]

However, when I make the request in Xcode it prints a different response to the console.

[image: Xcode Consol]

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    parseData()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func parseData(){
    var requestedLink: String
    let streamableLink = "https://api.streamable.com/import?url="
    requestedLink = "https://instagram.com/p/BVn8hvZgNQW/"
    let url1 = URL(string: "\(streamableLink)\(requestedLink)")
    print(url1)
    // parse data to the STREAMABLE API
    Alamofire.request("\(streamableLink)\(requestedLink)", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        print(response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let firstReply = json["shortcode"].stringValue
            print(firstReply)


            var shortCode: String
            let secondLinkToParse = "https://api.streamable.com/videos/"
            shortCode = "\(firstReply)"
            let url2 = URL(string: "\(secondLinkToParse)\(shortCode)")
            print(url2)
            // parse data to the STREAMABLE API
            Alamofire.request("\(secondLinkToParse)\(shortCode)", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    let secondReply = json["url"].stringValue
                    print(secondReply)

                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)

                }

            }
            case .failure(let error):
            print(error)

        }
    }
}
}
```

My question is why would the response be different? and how would I work around it? 
My guess is, maybe the request needs parameters?

Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you can post the actual URL you're calling?

Comment: @HPatel So to get a direct link using their API, I have to make 2 requests. The first one is to get a short code to identify the video. The second one is to get the url of that video. Here is an example [link](https://api.streamable.com/videos/myxln) notice the end of the link which is the shortcode.

Comment: Are you sending different headers?

Comment: @Ssswift How would I know? I don't really have that much experience in networking.

Comment: The easiest way might be to point both at a website like https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending that will tell you.  I'd also read the documentation (or source code) for your networking library.  Beyond that, there are many ways to inspect your network traffic, but that's beyond the scope of a comment box.

Comment: @Ssswift I don't think it is a headers problem. I have been able to get the same response in my browser and Xcode with this code `func makeRequest(){
        let reuestedURL = "https://api.streamable.com/videos/txv4q"
        Alamofire.request("\(reuestedURL)",method: .get, parameters: nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.response?.allHeaderFields)
                print(response)
                debugPrint(response)
        
     }` However, I'm still not sure why it's not printing the same response in my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's interested in using streamable API, the reason why I'm not getting a value for url is because videos takes time to be processed. When percent is at 100 there will be a value for url.